# In React.js, using componentWillUnmount to remove an event listener, how can I make sure the event listener gets removed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After the component is unmounted, I get errors when I resize the window. I know `window.removeEventListener` is being called, but it is acting as if it never gets called. The error says:

> warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or
>   mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the
>   HeaderMain component.

I even tried using a code example from the React docs, and it does the same thing my class was doing. From https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html:

```
import React from "react";

var HeaderMain = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {windowWidth: window.innerWidth};
  },

  handleResize: function(e) {
    this.setState({windowWidth: window.innerWidth});
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  },

  render: function() {
    return <div>Current window width: {this.state.windowWidth}</div>;
  }
});

module.exports = HeaderMain;
```

I've tried messing around with `bind()`, I've tried it in `ES6`, and tried different versions of `React.js`. I can't get rid of the error.

How do I make sure my event listener will get removed?

Comment: This code should run fine. You probably didn't actually paste the code that is demonstrating the problem.

Comment: No, I actually did. This code doesn't work, and it's almost identical from the example on the React docs, except for the last line. See my solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that it has to do with binding. When you call .bind(this), it returns a new function with the desired scope, so it wasn't unregistering the same function I thought I added.

Also, I found for whatever reason, in ES6 + React v15.3.1 (latest) the automatic binding doesn't occur (I thought it was supposed to) as it does in ES5 (same version of React), so I just stored a reference to the bound function, and reused it.

```
import React from "react";

export default class HeaderMain extends React.Component {

  boundFunc = this.handleResize.bind(this);

  constructor()
  {
    super();

    this.state = {height:window.innerHeight + "px"};
  }

  handleResize(e)
  {
    this.setState({height:window.innerHeight + "px"});
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
     window.addEventListener('resize', this.boundFunc);
  }

  componentWillUnmount()
  {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.boundFunc);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <header class="header_main" style={{height:this.state.height}}>
         Example Header
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This blog post explains the autobinding situation with ES6 classes http://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Interesting that in this case it actually helped me. I'm not sure what the solution would be in ES5.

Answer (score 0):

dont worry about this warning,you can test with a `console.log()` in `handleresize` function like this :

```
 handleResize: function(e) {
    this.setState({windowWidth: window.innerWidth} , function(){
    console.log("windowWidth" , windowWidth);
    });
  }
```

test it with change route or any action to call `componentWillUnmount` function and then open your `console` and resize window.